# How can I retrieve data from sql statement based on two table's criteria

Tags: c#, sql-server

I would like to retrieve data from my database, based on criteria from more than one table.

Example: I would like to retrieve the name(s) of the driver(s) that are allowed to drive on this routes (available routes array).

- I have two tables (DriverProfile and DriverProfileSettings).
- DriverProfile table contains the drivers Names.
- DriverProfileSettings table contains the Routes allowed (10,11,14 - these are varchars)
- DriverProfileSettings contains the DriverProfile table's primary keys (named DPS_Fk in DriverProfileSettings and in DriverProfile it is named DPS_K)

I tried doing it like this:

using (SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand("select[DP_Name] FROM dbo.DriverProfile dp inner join DriverProfileSettings dps on dp.DP_Pk = dps.DPS_DP_Fk where dps.[DPS_RouteAllocation] in  ("  + ' "myDriverAvailableRoutes[i] " ' + ")", con))

This doesn't seem to be working for me, can anyone help me out?

Also, I am coding in C#.

Comment: You should learn about SQL joins. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Hi.  What happens you run this code?  Do you get an error message?  If so, it helps to include that.  I would recommend you research [joins in SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt8wzxy4.aspx) and [SQL injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Sql Server you can change the select script as below.

```
select [DP_Name] FROM dbo.DriverProfile dp
inner join DriverProfileSettings dps
on dp.primarykey = dps.foreignkey
where dps.[DPS_RouteAllocation] in ('Your Location')
```

Comment: Thanks this seemed to work but now I get the following error :       Additional information: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '10,11,14' to data type int.

Comment: what is the datatype of the column DPS_RouteAllocation in database? If it is of INT then try passing the parameters '10,11,14' individually as  below. routelocation in ('14').

Comment: change the below statement in your c# code. in dbo.DriverProfileSettings = ' " + '10','11','14' + " ' ", con.   Add the single quotes ' as given.

Comment: Can you update the statement you gave me so I can work from that? As my statement is wrong.

Comment: will you be able to delimit the string '10,11,14' (arr[i])  to individual characters like '10','14' in your c# code? If you can do that, then below is the script                                                                                                          "select [DP_Name] FROM dbo.DriverProfile dp inner join DriverProfileSettings dps on dp.primarykey = dps.foreignkey where dps.[DPS_RouteAllocation] in ('Your Location') ' " + arr[delimitedchar] + " ' " , con

Comment: I could try that but could you check what I am trying to do now (updated the post), I think my quotes aren't in the right place.

Comment: "select [DP_Name] FROM dbo.DriverProfile dp inner join DriverProfileSettings dps on dp.primarykey = dps.foreignkey where dps.[DPS_RouteAllocation] in ( ' " + arr[delimitedchar] + " '  ) " , con

Comment: You sir are a genius! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad that helped you :)