# SQL Statement not retrieving any results

Tags: sql-server

I seem to have hit a hole in the road as my code (again) doesn't seem to be working: 
This is sort-of a follow up about my previous question regarding SQL inner joining. (You can view it here [How can I retrieve data from sql statement based on two table's criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43226772/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-sql-statement-based-on-two-tables-criteria))

So I am trying to retrieve data (Name(s) of drivers) based on criteria but after executing my SQL statement it seems to get no results.

Here is my SQL statement:

```
SqlCommand test = new SqlCommand( "SELECT[DP_Name] FROM[DriverProfile] dp 
inner join DriverProfileSettings dps on dps.DPS_DP_Fk = dp.DP_Pk 
where dps.[DPS_RouteAllocation] in  ( '  " + "8" + " '  )",con);
```

In my database:

- DriverProfile table contains the Name (DP_Name)
- DriverProfileSettingscontains the Routes the driver is allowed to drive in (DPS_RouteAllocation), for now I set their values to "8" (without quotes) in order to test my sql statement.
- DriverProfileSettings also contains the Primary key (DPS_DP_Fk) of DriverProfile.

Note:

- I have tried removing the single quotes ( ' ') and so on from that statement but it still doesn't show any results.
- I am coding in C# (using Visual Studio)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: if you run your query directly in SQL (using SSMS or any other tool), does it return the results you expect? That way we can rule out an issue with the C# part.

Comment: You have spaces around your 8. Try changing to `( '" + "8" + "'  )`, or if DPS_RouteAllocation is a numeric field, then remove the single quotes to get `( " + "8" + "  )`

Comment: marc_s I will try and look into that thanks. Adyson I have tried that as well, so I am unsure whether my statement is correct or not.

Comment: BeanFrog thank you very much that seemed to have fixed the problem!

Comment: Excellent - I made it an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have spaces around your 8. Try changing to `( '" + "8" + "' )`, or if `DPS_RouteAllocation` is a numeric field, then remove the single quotes to get `( " + "8" + " )`